# What is the Swift 3 equivalent of NSURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent()?

Tags: swift, xcode, nsurl, swift3

I'm following [a basic tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1) on building a simple iOS app in Swift.

It is written in Swift 2.x, and I work with XCode 8 Beta and Swift 3.

The tutorial suggests using `NSFileManager` to find a data directory. Class names have changed, so the auto-fixed Swift 3 looks like this:

```
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urlsForDirectory(.documentDirectory, inDomains:.userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("meals")
```

However, Xcode now complains that

```
Value of type 'URL' has no member 'URLByAddingPathComponent'
```

I am unable to find out what the method is called now.

The [NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/) doesn't contain any hints as to how to address it from Swift 3

- What is the new method name?
- Where do I have to go to find a complete class reference for Swift 3 (or, the Swift 3 interface to the library the `URL` class is defined in - I still don't completely understand the nomenclature) so I can research these myself in the future?

Comment: Just .appendingPathComponent(

Comment: Take a look at the [new `NSURL` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl) – it's now `appendingPathComponent(_:)`

Comment: @Hamish argh, so I was looking at the wrong class reference. Thanks! I suppose I could delete this. (Edit: ah, there's an answer now. Do you want to post one yourself Hamish? Otherwise I'll edit the reference link into K.Nimo's answer.)

Comment: You should update to beta 4

Comment: Your code will change again after updating. You will need to use urls(for:in:) method for the documents directory and the appendingPathComponent won't throw anymore. Much cleaner

Comment: By the way, you may want to `FileManager.default` rather than `FileManager()`.

Comment: You can also cmd-click on `URL` in the Xcode editor, to jump to its definition. You should quickly find the methods which you need.

Answer (score 43):

As of Xcode 8 beta 4, it is named [`appendingPathComponent(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1410614-urlbyappendingpathcomponent), and does not throw.

```
static let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")
```

Also as [Leo Dabus points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812240/what-is-the-swift-3-equivalent-of-nsurl-urlbyappendingpathcomponent/38812350#comment64992172_38812240), your `documentsDirectory` property will need changing to use [`urls(for:in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407726-urlsfordirectory) in beta 4:

```
static let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
```

<sup>(Note that I've made your property names `lowerCamelCase`, as per the [Swift API design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#conventions). I would also recommend using `FileManager.default`, rather than creating a new instance.)</sup>

You can take a look at [Apple's latest API reference guide](https://developer.apple.com/reference) to see the API naming changes that have taken place in Swift 3.

Answer (score 12):

It has now changed to `appendingPathComponent(_:)` and it throws, so you need to wrap it in do - catch block

```
do {
  let archiveURL = try documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent("meals")
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

**Update**

As per Xcode 8 beta 4, the [`appendingpathcomponent(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1410614-urlbyappendingpathcomponent) do not throw error.

For relevant info see answer by [@Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38812350/5861569)

Answer (score 4):

```
func appendingPathComponent(String)
```

=> Returns a new URL made by appending a path component to the original URL.

```
static let archiveURL = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent("meals")
```

If it is directory:

```
func appendingPathComponent(String, isDirectory: Bool)
```

=> Returns a new URL made by appending a path component to the original URL, along with a trailing slash if the component is designated a directory.

```
static let archiveURL = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent("meals", isDirectory: true)
```