# How does one access the path to a created folder in Navigation pane (left pane)?

Tags: ios, swift, filepath

I've created a folder in the left pane, which holds various images.
It's called "wikiImages".
How do I access this folder or get the path to this folder?

I found `Bundle.main.resourcePath!`, but this seems to access all assets.

Is there a way to access the path to the folder "wikiImages'?

Comment: is this `wikiImages` folder built into your application bundle or is it files that the user downloads (into `Documents`, for example)?

Comment: Hi, It's built into my application bundle. No user downloads. These images come with the package, so they are built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `wikiImages` lives inside your application bundle's resources folder, you can do something like:

```
if let resourceFolderURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL {
    let wikiFolderURL = resourceFolderURL.appendingPathComponent("wikiImages")
}
```

Like as described [in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812240/what-is-the-swift-3-equivalent-of-nsurl-urlbyappendingpathcomponent).